# Using `extend self` and `class << self` in Ruby Modules

Tags: ruby, module, extend

I sometimes write modules that will only contain module methods (as opposed to module *instance* methods) (are there better names for these?). These modules should not be included in classes because that would have no effect and be misleading to a reader. So I'd like it to be as clear as possible to the reader that these modules contain no instance methods.

If I define all methods with `.self`, then a reader has to inspect all methods to ensure that this module contains no instance methods. If I instead use `class << self` or `extend self` then it is automatic; as soon as the reader sees this, they know.

I think `extend self` is best becuase with `class << self` one has to find its corresponding `end`; that is, it may not apply to *all* methods in the module.

So is it a good idea, and a best practice, to use `extend self` in cases like this?

Also, is there any difference *at runtime* between enclosing all methods in `class << self` as opposed to using `extend self`?

Comment: Is it your intention that the methods of YourModule be called as `YourModule.some_method`? Could you provide some examples? Also, I had to look up what `extend self` does, I've never seen it, whereas I know what `def self.method` and `class << self` do.

Comment: Yes, my intention was for the module method names to be referred to using the module name, e.g. `MyModule.foo`. This tells the reader a) where it is defined, and b) context in addition to the method name as to what it does. I too recently learned about `extend self` and already knew the other forms.

Answer (score 3):

> I sometimes write modules that will only contain module methods (as opposed to module instance methods) (are there better names for these?).

[Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), meaning a class with a single instance. Here that "single instance" is the Module instance.

> If I define all methods with .self, then a reader has to inspect all methods to ensure that this module contains no instance methods

The module's documentation should make this clear. If the user of a module has to study the code to understand your module, that is a documentation failure.

## What does `extend self` do?

> *So I'd like it to be as clear as possible to the reader that these modules contain no instance methods.*

`extend self` does the opposite. It makes all the instance methods also be class methods. It's equivalent to `YourModule.extend(YourModule)`.

```
module YourModule
  def some_method
    23
  end

  extend self
end
```

Is the same as...

```
module YourModule
  def some_method
    23
  end
end

YourModule.extend(YourModule)
```

Which is similar to...

```
module YourModule
  def some_method
    23
  end

  def self.some_method
    23
  end
end
```

Why would you do this? To allow both...

```
YourModule.some_method
```

and also...

```
class SomeClass
  extend YourModule
end

SomeClass.some_method
```

There are edge cases where you might want this, but for general use I would argue this is an anti-pattern. The first is using a module as a singleton, the second is using the module as a mixin or trait. These are two rather different design goals for a module. Trying to be both will compromise the design of both.

## Pros and Cons.

Since the primary use case of being both a singleton and a mixin is an anti-pattern, I would argue use `class << self`, with `def self.method` occasionally, and `module_function` and `extend self` never.

### `class << self`

Pros

- All class definitions are grouped together.
- The block scope makes it clear what affects the class and what affects the instances.
- Indentation makes it clear what is in the block.
- IDEs can clearly identify what is in the block.
- It allows using normal declarations like `attr_accessor` on the class.
- [It is documented](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.2/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Singleton+Classes).
- It is common.
- Rubocop approved.

Cons

- When looking at an individual method, it's not as obvious as `def self.method`.

### `def self.method`

Pros

- It's obvious it's a class method from looking at the method.
- [It is documented](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.2/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Scope).
- It is common.
- Rubocop approved.

Cons

- You might forget to add the `self.`.
- It allows mixing of class and instance methods making the reader hunt through the code.
- It does not help using `attr_accessor` and friends on the class.

### `extend self`

Pros

- It allows your module to act as both a singleton (`YourModule.method`) and a mixin (`extend YourModule`)... which is also a con.

Cons

- It is obscure; many (most?) won't know to look for it or what it means if they find it.
- It is [not documented](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.2/Object.html#method-i-extend) (or if it is, I can't find it).
- Individual methods look like instance methods.
- It can appear anywhere in the module, and there's no consensus where it should go, making it [action at a distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_(computer_programming)).
- It affects the meaning of code *before* it, the one case I can think of this in Ruby, further making it [action at a distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_(computer_programming)).
- [Rubocop prefers `module_function`](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/1.39/cops_style.html) to `extend self`, though doesn't explain why. For my guesses, see below.
- It allows your module to act as both a singleton (`YourModule.method`) and a mixin (`extend YourModule`). Those are two rather different use cases making this an anti-pattern.

### `module_function`

I've never heard of this either, but it came up when searching for `extend self`. I would also say to never use this, use `class << self`, but it's better than `extend self`.

Pros

- It's at least [mentioned in the Modules and Classes documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.2/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Methods).
- It's [documented](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#method-i-module_function).
- It works like `private` in that it affects all methods below it (though this is also a con, see below).
- If there are to be no instance methods, it must appear at the top of the module.
- Rubocop approved.

Cons

- It is obscure; many (most?) won't know to look for it or what it means when they find it.
- Individual methods look like instance methods.
- It affects the meaning of distant code after it making it [action at a distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance_(computer_programming)).

Comment: Thanks for that detailed response. 
Wow, it did not occur to me that `extend self` left the instance methods remaining, I thought those methods would be _only_ module methods. An article at https://medium.com/rubycademy/is-module-function-really-the-same-as-extend-self-ac1e96a1cda0 discusses some of the differences between `module_function` and `extend self`.
This means that `class << self` is the only way (other than defining all method names as preceded by `self.`) to have _only_ module methods.

Comment: Sure, documentation should mention it, but it's best to indicate something like this in the code as well if such a construct is available.

Comment: Regarding `extend self`, I don't think it changes every module method into an instance method. Rather, it _adds_ a module method corresponding to the instance method. I didn't know what `extend self` did until recently either, but I did know that `extend` brings a module's instance methods into a class as class methods. Specifying `self` instead of another module just does this to itself instead of to another module.

Comment: Regarding the use of `extend self` and `module_function`, I find it is helpful when writing a library for use by other developers, especially developers outside of one's organization (an open source library, for example). I prefer specifying a module name in the method call to be explicit, but someone else might not. So this gives them the choice.

Comment: @KeithBennett "*I prefer specifying a module name in the method call to be explicit, but someone else might not.*" If you're saying you want someone to be able to both `YourModule.method` and also `extend YourModule`, one can instead use delegation. But I'd question the motivation; they are two different things: one is a singleton, the other a mixin/trait. And its very easy for users to mix up `extend` vs `include`. It's better to design your module as a singleton, or as a mixin/trait using `include YourModule`.

Comment: A reminder that there is also [Object#define_singleton_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method) and `singleton_class.define_method`, using [Object#singleton_class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) and [Module#define_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method).

Comment: Delegation and defining singleton methods would be more verbose in that they would have to be done for each method in the module, right? And if the module changed, one would need to modify the corresponding delegating or defining code? Also, as I said, I want to offer two ways of using the API depending on the user's needs. It doesn't matter to me that one is a singleton and another is a trait. Also, I am not concerned about the user confusing include and extend; they will find out quickly if they get it wrong.

Comment: Regarding the use of `extend YourModule`, in general I do _not_ want it to be used on these modules. I did not intend to suggest using `YourModule.method` and `extend YourMethod`, but rather, `YourModule.method` and `include YourModule`. For me, an important benefit of having them be module class methods, "singleton" methods as Schwern calls them, is that one precedes the method name with the module name when calling them. To me, this makes the code more explicit and comprehensible.

Comment: By the way, I do realize we are now discussing two conflicting use cases here: 1) that of my original question, where I do _not_ want these methods used as instance methods, and 2) other use cases, e.g. open source libraries, where I _do_ want instance methods to be an alternate interface to the methods.

Comment: @KeithBennett 1) Rather than hinting with code, I would recommend direct comments, documentation, and Cary's advice to raise when included, 2) you have my thoughts on that use case, however,  your question could be updated to make what you're asking for clear so others can answer.

Comment: Schwern, thanks for your input. My original question is what I did want to know, and the answer seems to be to use `class << self` for what I want. The additional use case where I want to make an open source library module available in multiple modes is outside the scope of that question. So I think the question should remain as is, no?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it should matter how you decide to define the module methods. Consider simply raising an exception if the module is included in another module (which may be a class). You can do that with the callback (a.k.a. "hook") method [Module#included](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-included). Here's an example.

```
module M
  # This module is not to be included in a class because
  # it contains no instance methods.
  
  def self.included(klass)
    raise "\nYou intended to include this module in #{klass}. You must be out of\nyour mind! It does no harm but there is no point in doing so\nbecause this module contains no instance methods. Duh!"
  end
  
  def self.hi
    puts "Hi, guys"
  end
end
```

```
M.hi
Hi, guys
```

```
class C
  include M
end
RuntimeError: 
You intended to include this module in C. You must be out of
your mind! It does no harm but there is no point in doing so
because this module contains no instance methods. Duh!
```

Comment: I like the defensive programming.

Comment: As I mentioned, I would like the code to make it as clear as possible _when the developer is reading it_ that none of the methods are instance methods. The indentation required for `class << self` may be more readily apparent than an implementation of `self.included`. Your approach works at runtime but adds some functionality that I may not want to have to include, especially since one would need to do the same thing with `self.prepended` as you did with `self.included`.

Comment: Keith, if your sole objective is to tell someone reading the module code that the module does not contain any instance methods how can you improve on just having a comment at the beginning of the file that states that fact?

Comment: Comments often go stale, and are therefore less trustworthy than executable code. Also, with the comment alone, another developer might inadvertently add an instance in the future. At least with the `class << self` approach, the different-ness of such a move would be more obvious. That said, I *do* agree that a comment is helpful.